# NHibernate mapping GeneratedBy.SequenceIdentity("seq") where PK is a string

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, identity

I am trying to map a PK in an Oracle table with Fluent NHibernate. The PK is a string (the database schema cannot be changed). The PK is generted by a Sequence. This is a legacy database, there is no trigger on the table, only the sequence.

With Fluent NHibernate, I am trying

```
this.Id(x => x.Id)
    .Column("FOO_ID")
    .Not.Nullable()
    .GeneratedBy
    .SequenceIdentity("SEQ");
```

but am receiving

> Identity type must be integral (int, long, uint, ulong)

because `SequenceIdentity()` checks that the value is an integral.

How do I achieve this with a string PK? The same approach with a integral id works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know that Oracle supports string sequences. But anyway, I don't believe that NHibernate supports string sequences out of the box.

However you can [create your own ID generators in NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate.aspx).

You will probably find that you need something similar to the inbuilt [SequenceGenerator](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/SequenceGenerator.cs) class, so I would start with that code and see what you can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was

```
CustomSqlType("VARCHAR2")
```

The PK id mapping:

```
this.Id(x => x.Id)
    .Column("FOO_ID")
    .Not.Nullable()
    .GeneratedBy.Sequence("SEQ_FOO")
    .CustomSqlType("VARCHAR2");
```